# variable incrementer in setInterval function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, setinterval

I have lot of problems with a function and I get confused with the variable scope. I tried with a callback function, but I cannot get it.

I have a function to animate a background with css. I need that function doesn't restart the incrementer variable  to 0 when I click for a second time while a setInterval is running.
See that when you click a twice  in  time1 or time2 of html, the order of counter doesn't hold the order.

```
function movie(elm,jumpPx,spriteHeight,duration){
var inc=0;
var time=setInterval(function(){

    if(inc<spriteHeight){
        inc+=jumpPx;
        //elm.style.backgroundPosition='0px -'+inc+'px';
        elm.innerHTML=inc;
    }else{
        clearInterval(time);
        elm.style.backgroundPosition='0px -0px';          
    }
},duration);
```

}

```
<p onclick="movie(this,1,1000,1000)">time1</p>
<p onclick="movie(this,1,1000,1000)">time2</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add language tags when applicable, they will highly increase the probability of the right person seeing your question.

Comment: Ok man, I'm newest here the next time I wil do it. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your variable declaration is within the function:

```
function movie(elm,jumpPx,spriteHeight,duration){
    var inc=0;
    ... other code ...
}
```

Therefore, each time the function is called, it resets 'inc' to 0.

```
var inc = 0;
function movie(elm,jumpPx,spriteHeight,duration){
    ... other code ...
}
```

If you move it outside the function, it won't keep resetting

Comment: Thanks man, but when I do this and click firts in "time1" the timer starts and if you click seconds later on time2 this doesn't start by 0.

Comment: Clicking on either time1 or time2 will increment the var inc by one as they both call the same function. What exactly do you want to achieve when you click each button ?

Comment: I need that Interval starts counting from 0 in each call, and the timer runs parallel to the element that has been clicked before. Each event handler works parallel without affecting to another counter.

Comment: In that case you're going to need two functions, each with an independent counter in. Each button will then fire off it's own function and therefore it's own counter.

Comment: I can't vote up you yet because I'm newest here and I dont have enough reputation, but thank you so much!!